# Flutter - firestore error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code snippet to query firestore:

```
  FirebaseTransactionRepository(this.userId) : transactionCollection = firestore.FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('transactions');
   var query = transactionCollection.orderBy('created_date', descending: transactionQuery.sortOrder == SortOption.Newest);

    if (transactionQuery.fromDate != null) {
      query = transactionCollection.where('created_date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: transactionQuery.fromDate);
    }
    if (transactionQuery.toDate != null) {
      query = transactionCollection.where('created_date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: transactionQuery.toDate);
    }
    if (transactionQuery.lastDocument != null) {
      query = query.startAfterDocument(transactionQuery.lastDocument!);
    }
    return query.limit(transactionQuery.limit).get().then((snapshot) {
      final List<Transaction> transactions = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Transaction.fromEntity(TransactionEntity.fromSnapshot(doc))).toList();
      firestore.DocumentSnapshot? lastDocument;
      if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        lastDocument = snapshot.docs.last;
      }
      return TransactionQueryResult(transactions: transactions, query: transactionQuery.copyWith(lastDocument: lastDocument));
    });
```

However that is giving me the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query. You have an inequality where filter (whereLessThan(), whereGreaterThan(), etc.) on field 'created_date' and so you must also have 'created_date' as your first orderBy() field, but your first orderBy() is currently on field '**name**' instead.

What is strange to me is that I already use `created_date` for my first and only orderBy. I'm not sure how is the field '**name**' is related here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could fix it by changing the order of the statements:

```
    firestore.Query<Object?> query;
    if (transactionQuery.contactIDs != null && transactionQuery.contactIDs!.isNotEmpty) {
      query = transactionCollection.where('cid', whereIn: transactionQuery.contactIDs);
    }
    if (transactionQuery.fromDate != null) {
      query = transactionCollection.where('created_date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: transactionQuery.fromDate);
    }
    if (transactionQuery.toDate != null) {
      query = transactionCollection.where('created_date', isLessThanOrEqualTo: transactionQuery.toDate);
    }
    query = transactionCollection.orderBy('created_date', descending: transactionQuery.sortOrder == SortOption.Newest);
```

(`orderBy` should be used after `where` methods)